# jQuery validate problems - not working - form just submits

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have read everything I could find here on this subject. I think the problem is simple and easy but I can not find out. I would be glad for some rested eyes to take a quick look. What am I doing wrong here? This simple form just submits and does not validate. My problem is in a bigger form but I found out I should test it simple first. I even tested on jsfiddle and do not understand the response there either http://jsfiddle.net/asle/fmYLP/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Validate Example Page</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function(){
        $("#testform").validate();
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="testform" name="testform" method="post">Name:
    <input name="testname" type="text" />
    <br />Adress:
    <input name="testadress" type="text" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to add "required" to the input and it works. Do I always have to add "required" to every field? It is not like that in the demos. `<input required name="testname" type="text" />`

Answer (score 3):

[According to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), your way is "not recommended": `jQuery().ready(function(){...})`.

Instead use `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...})`

or `jQuery(function(){...})`

---

**Quote OP:**

> This simple form just submits and does not validate.

Because you have not declared any validation rules, so the form is always valid no matter what kind of data you enter, or with no data at all.

**Quote OP's Comment:**

> I tried to add "required" to the input and it works. Do I always have
>   to add "required" to every field? It is not like that in the demos.
>   `<input required name="testname" type="text" />`

I'm not sure which demos you're talking about, but **you must declare validation rules *someplace***, otherwise, how do you expect the plugin to know which fields are `required` or apply another kind of rule?

Here are three valid examples...

By inline `attribute` (HTML 5):

```
<input required="required" name="testname" type="text" />
```

or by `class`:

```
<input class="required" name="testname" type="text" />
```

or [via `.validate()` in jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#testform").validate({
        rules: {
            testname: {
                required: true,
                // another rule
            },
            testaddress: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4HSYz/**

---

There are also methods available for manipulating the rules dynamically.

See [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

---

Read the full documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I was talking about these demos: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ but I understand it now. The missing "required" in the input field or other rules in the function. I have other forms that validate but I had rules for them. Thanks for clearing up a blury mind on a Sunday. I will not make this mistake again! - :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('#testform').validate();
});
```